# How to delete multi level cookie in CakePHP 2.5.3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-2.5

I have made multi level cookie like this:

```
$cookie_data = array(
    'value1' => 1,
    'value2' => 2,
    'value3' => array(
        'value1' => 1,
        'value2' => 2
    )
);
$this->Cookie->write('mycookie', $cookie_data);
```

Everything works fine until I want to delete this whole cookie.
I have tried:

```
 $this->Cookie->delete('mycookie');
 $this->Cookie->destroy();
```

But after this, when I try to read the cookie with `$this->Cookie->read('mycookie');`, It's back again.

How to delete this multi level cookie properly?

Comment: It's in title - 2.5.3

Comment: try to debug this - `debug($this->Cookie->delete('mycookie'));`

Comment: as per the documentation it should be deleted. there was an isuue with older version but it is fixed.

Comment: `$this->Cookie->destroy();` is deleteing all cookies. but `$this->Cookie->delete('mycookie');` deleting on 2nd reload.there might be some issue with this.

Comment: Are you reading the cookie within the same request?  Cookies will only be modified when headers are sent out to the browser so the updated cookie array will only be visible on the *next* request.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($cookie_data as $key=>$val){
    $this->Cookie->delete("mycookie.$key");
}
```

Comment: no need for this. cake should delete this with above code.

Comment: somwwhere i read it that i have to delete each key of cookie so in that case we have to loop it like this.

Comment: it was in 1.3 or  around that.this issue has been solved in 2.x.